# Rails application with legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an API that will look for data in a "non-rails-database". It already exists and was not created with the rails project. What is the best approach to use in this case ? Let's say I have a table called User in  this database, I would like to be able to do something like this in the controller: `User.last` or `User.find(id)`. It would be good, because I have to send back to the frontend as a JSON.
Should I use PORO Models ? How would it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your models then set table name and primary key explicitly, this helps you call active record methods in a controller

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 self.primary_key = 'user table primary key'
 self.table_name = 'user table name'
end
```

ref http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name-3D

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer to have them in PORO. For me, it makes things clear and gives more flexibility.

For an example, I would have a seperate folder called `api_models` in the `app` folder and have the classes there.

First, it may feel like you are duplicating the code, but it will give you an object to work with when API needs changes.

E.g

```
ApiModel::User
  ...  
end
```

also,

if you wanting be bit more advance and thinking about versioning (if not you should ;) etc, I would recommend a gem like [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape), because that handles lot of api related things and all you need to focus is the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create custom methods that contain custom DB queries that override ActiveRecord methods. Because model classes inherit from ActiveRecord, if you define a method in the model class with the same method name as the ActiveRecord method, then when you call it, the model class will be called. You can still call the ActiveRecord method if you call `super`

So, assuming you already setup the connection to the DB, you can do something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def self.find(id)
    sql = "Select * from ... where id = ..."
    records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

So when you call find it will call the `User` `find`, and not the `ActiveRecord` `find`. You can also define a custom method so that you don't override the `ActiveRecord` `find`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def self.new_find(id)
    sql = "Select * from ... where id = ..."
    records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

Not sure if its the best approach but its an approach :)